# How to create a custom tooltip with a icon?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to create custom tooltip in the JavaFX SceneBuilder, but so far trial&error didn't yield anything usable and Google wasn't helpful either.

The custom tooltip should basically be an image (little "info icon") combined with the stock tooltip element of the SceneBuilder.

Unfortunately you can't drag this stock tooltip on imported media...

Is there a way to do this? Would appreciate any hints

Comment: Can you set html in a tooltip like you could do in swing? This might be another approach.

Comment: Don't think that will work, as you have to snap the tooltip to an element and can't place/move it where you need it. Basically I need the info icon image as an element so that I can snap the tooltip to it.

Comment: Tooltip content can be customized at will using its `graphic` attribute. From within the Scenebuilder, you can drag any component in the tooltip, or even build entire graphs with layouts; it will be visible in the preview mode. Do not forget to remove the tooltip's text.